# Сложить два массива php

Tags: php, массивы

есть два массива:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [date_create] => 2019-07-11 10:10:59
            [id] => 40604334
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [date_create] => 2019-07-11 09:15:11
            [id] => 40603954
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [date_create] => 2019-07-11 08:11:51
            [id] => 40603720
        )
)

Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => текст
            [1] => 2019-07-11 10:41:55
            [2] => link
            [id] => 40604334
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => текст
            [1] => 2019-07-11 09:55:09
            [2] => link
            [id] => 40545434
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => текст
            [1] => 2019-07-11 09:32:10
            [2] => link
            [id] => 40556772
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => текст
            [1] => 2019-07-11 09:22:18
            [2] => link
            [id] => 40603954
        )
)
```

Как сделать так, чтобы взять id из второго массива, найти его в первом массиве и добавить deate_create во второй массив (в нужную ячейку массива)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваша задача решается следующим способом:

```php
foreach ($data1 as $array1) {
    foreach ($data2 as $key => $array2) {
        if ($array1['id'] == $array2['id']) {
            // Как я понял, дата во втором массиве хранится в элементе с индексом '1'
            $data2[$key][1] = $array1['date_create'];
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Не понял, как решает это мою задачу. date_create не добавляется же во второй массив. Основной массив - это второй массив. Мне к нему date_Create нужно запихнуть по нужному id

Comment: У вас в вопросе написано: «добавить `date_create` в первый массив», вы всё-таки определитесь, что вам нужно.

Comment: Не правильно написал. Основной второй массив. Нужно из первого массива взять date_create и запихнуть во второй по нужному id

Comment: Поменяйте массивы местами и всё, отредактировал свой пост с учётом вашего комментария.

Comment: Спасибо, помогло. Вы заменяете их местами, ну я просто добавил к массиву новое значение.

Answer (score 1):

сделайте из второго массива ассоциативный с датами

```
$arr2 = array_column($arr2, 'id', 1);
```

получите значения вида `[ 40604334 => '2019-07-11 10:41:55']`

затем пройдитесь по первому, и замените значения

```
foreach($arr1 as &$v){
   $v['date_create'] = $arr2[$v['id']]; 
}
```

можно варианты предложить со всякими там `array_map` и прочими `array_intersect_key`, но это все будет куда сложнее выглядеть и поэтому не имеет смысла.

Comment: У меня второй массив - основной. Там разные даты в двух массивов. Мне именно надо взять значение из первого массива и запихнуть во второй по нужному id

Comment: @АртурАтласов а в вопросе наоборот написано. Какая разница, в приведенном коде поменяйте массивы местами. будет у вас `$arr1 = array_column($arr1, 'date_create', 'id')`, и цикл по второму.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 0):

Еще вариант:

```
$e = array_column($array1, null, 'id');
$output = array_map(
    function ($itm) use ($e) {
        $id = $itm['id'];
        if (isset($e[$id])) {
            $itm[1] = $e[$id]['date_create'];
        }
        return $itm;
    },
    $array2
);
```

[DEMO](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/eb0015b3d28caaa138ef669642240caa089ea290)